# Excel VBA - Find on merged cell

Tags: vba, excel, find

I am not able to using VBA find function on a merged cell. If I unmerge that cell, it finds that cell correctly. Is there any solution to this?

```
Private Sub FindTry()
    Dim oFind As Range

    With Sheet2
        Set oFind = .Cells.Find("/", , xlValues, xlPart)

        If oFind Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "/ NOT found"
        Else
            MsgBox "/ found"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Here is link to file [download link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1h5ZjR7_0QZTkvVgGVitTa9ziPdqnRh9q/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Is `16/17 Fixed Grade` a value or a formula?

Comment: Your code works for me, are you sure it's in `Sheet2` code name ? Maybe your `Worksheets("Sheet2")` has a different codename ?

Comment: @RobinMackenzie Value

Comment: @ShaiRado Yes, sheet2 is a code name of worksheet I am trying to find in

Comment: Works for me too... both with `xlFormulas` and `xlValues` options.

Comment: Yep, your code works, in my own test as well as in the file you provided.

Comment: Does that mean my excel setup is corrupted? P.s. I am able to find it manaully but no though VBA